# 10-bit displays and JNDs

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, rendering

I have been doing some preliminary work on 30-bit displays (specifically, the DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10X2 format and related OpenGL RGB10A2 format) and have a question regarding a slide from the [WinHEC 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463168) presentation by Chas Boyd and David Glen on [Display Technologies](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/e/6/5e66b27b-988b-4f50-af3a-c2ff1e62180f/gra-t583_wh08.pptx) (<- warning - large powerpoint) showing JNDs vs. display brightness:
[image]

It's pretty clear that they're showing typical display brightness in the dark bar in the 150-400 cd/m^2 range, and the advantage of a 10 bit over 8 bit display in the number of JNDs for a given brightness.

Does anyone know why there are *two* curves (A and B) being shown here?  There's nothing in the adjacent slides or notes that describe what the two curves represent, so I'm not sure if those are two different display technologies, or values from competing theories on the human visual system, or what.

FYI - my only experience with JNDs is from the [DICOM 3.14 standard](http://medical.nema.org/dicom/2004/04_14PU.PDF)

Anyone recognize this graph, attend the conference, or have an informed opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do reference High Precision and Extended Range in the adjacent slides, as well as earlier in introducing >24 bpp formats. My guess would be that A is High Precision and B is Extended Range. This is due to the additional bias factor which could be used to increase JND above and beyond what High Precision does, although it does lose the 2-bit alpha channel.

However I wasn't there so can't be certain.

Comment: Interesting idea @Guvante.  It looks like the Extended Range format is now known as DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10_XR_BIAS_A2_UNORM [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557519(v=vs.85).aspx))   It's a little strange that they don't go into the Extended Range details until after this slide, but that could just have been the presenters preference...

Comment: I don't think that's the correct explanation, however, since the graph is showing JNDs as a function of device brightness.  As I interpret it, High Precision can display 2^10 or 1024 digital driving levels.  The A and B curves seem like they must be perceptual responses of some kind.

Comment: The graph's maximum is 1024 for that reason (no way to get more than 1024 JND's off 1024 driving levels). If my interpretation is correct then the Extended Range would effectively have 4096 driving levels due to the extra 2 bits, which would allow it to have more JND's over the same range.